# IBAction function does not fire in class that inherits from UIPageViewControllerDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, ibaction

I have the following class definition and IBAction.  The class is the class I am using for root / first / master "page" in my UIPageViewController set.  (i.e. the master UIPageController that all the other controllers are loaded into.)

```
import UIKit


class MasterPageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, SideBarDelegate  {

    var iobj_NearbyPlacesViewController: NearbyPlacesViewController!
    var iobj_PageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var ia_StoryBoardNames: [String] = ["NearbyPlacesViewController","NearbyCitiesViewController", "SearchViewController"]
    var ii_CurrentPageIndex: Int = 0

    @IBAction func btnMenuClick(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        gobj_sideBar.showSideBar(!gobj_sideBar.isSideBarOpen)
    }
```

I have double checked and ensured the button on my storyboard scene is linked to the action and it is.  The challenge is that when I click on the button, the action is never called.  I have tried adding a new button to the scene and linking that up to a different action event and that does not get called either.  Any idea of what I am doing wrong and how I can get this to work?  Please let me know.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help you. If you really have an IBAction and it's really linked to your button in IB, it will fire. However, how does the button in your page view controller's "master view controller" show up on-screen?

If memory serves, a page view controller's entire content view is filled one of it's pages. If you want a page view controller and other stuff on the screen at the same time then you have to make the page view controller a child of another view controller.

Comment: You need to show us the layout of your MasterPageViewController and the UIPageViewController it manages as well as how the object ownership works.

Comment: Duncan - thank you for your comments.  I would not really have know how to "show" you the layout of the MasterPageViewController and the UIPageViewController as well as the object ownership as IB does not really seem to allow me to copy the UI Code and paste it.  Regardless I discovered the root of my problem and will post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I was just being very silly.  Everything was set up 100% correct with regard to actions etc.  The problem was that I made the background of the child / content page clear and did not see its actual boundaries when it was loaded.  As it turns out, once I changed the background color to white so I could see that I it was actually loading completely over top of the master view controller.  Thus, although I could see the button I wanted to click because that content page had a clear background, I was actually clicking on the transparent background of the content page and not actually on the button in the master page.  Once I resized the content page to not overlap the button area of the master page, everything worked fine.  Thanks for all the help.